# Save a single character

Tags: qt

everyone. 
I've created a simple textedit application. 
I would like to take the single character whenever the user writes it using the keyboard. 
I've thought to solve the problem in the following way:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    QString str= ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

    if (str.size()==0){
        pos=0;
    } else {      
        if(pos<str.size()) {
            QChar char_prel=str.at(pos);
            pos++;
            chars.push_back(char_prel);
        } else {
            pos=0;
            QString str=ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
            chars.clear();

            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                QChar char_prel=str.at(i);
                chars.push_back(char_prel);
                pos++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The solution doesn't work because everytime, i read the entire string on the edit block using:

```
 QString str= ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

and from that string i take the last inserted character. 
I want to do the same thing without using the toPlaintText(). 
Thanks for answering

Comment: You might handle the key press events of the `ui->textEdit` widget.

Comment: and how can I take the inserted character?

Comment: Hi @MartinaPianist96, if the answer helped you, please accept it when you can: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

If you handle the [KeyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#keyPressEvent) of the QTextEdit, you'll have a parameter of QKeyEvent* type, let's call this one "e".

Then you can use "e->text()" to get the corresponding character.

Comment: I get it. Thanks so much

Comment: if the answer helped you, please accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: UV (also for your help through remark in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62371441/2458991 ^^)