# How do I delete an instance of the class?

Tags: c++

```
class MyStrValArray {
    private:
    vector<char> p;
    public:
    void init(const int n);
    void clear();
    unsigned capacity();
    unsigned size(); 
    };


int main()
{
    MyStrValArray p1;

    ...

    if(p1.capacity() == p1.size())
    {
        MyStrValArray p2;
        p2.init(p1.size()*2);
        p2 = p1;
        p1.clear(); // I'm trying to delete the whole p1 instance, not the data inside p1.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is: when the memory of p1 is full, make another instance p2, with double of p1's size, copy all the data inside p1 to p2, and then remove p1.

How can I delete an instance of the class? If I use .clear(), I'm just deleting all the elements inside, not the instance itself. Is there any way to delete an instance?

Comment: Typically, you would do this expanding of memory *inside* an instance of the class. Incidentally, what you describe is exactly what std::vector does.

Comment: *p1* being a local var you cannot call delete on it, the compiler manages it by itself. But why do you not want to continue with *p1* ? you use a *vector* you can expand as you want while you have virtual memory to do

Comment: MyStrValArray *p1 = new MyStrValArray;
and 
delete p1. but Peter is right.

Comment: A more technical answer is that when an object gets destroyed depends on the way it was created. Global objects get destroyed when the program ends; objects with "automatic storage duration" (local variables) get destroyed when the scope is left (the closing curly brace is met); and only the destruction of dynamically allocated objects (with new) can be initiated at arbitrary places in the code by calling `free`.

Comment: Maybe should take a look at the reference for [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). All of the things you are trying to do (get size/capacity, grow when full) are done _automatically_ by `std::vector`. It may save you some work.

Comment: Yeim Kang is my answer useful for you ?

Answer (score 3):

you cannot 'delete' a local var and you do not need to do that, you want something like :

```
if(p1.capacity() == p1.size())
{
    p1.reserve(p1.size() * 2);
}
```

but your use of the *reverse* is quite useless, you can let `std::vector` to work to manage that by itself, except if you need to have *iterator* still valid after adding elements in a way compatible with the reserve size (see remarks on that answer)

---

About local var :

```
// here v does not exist
{
   // here v does not exist
   MyStrValArray v; // whatever the type
   std::cout << "blahblah" << std::endl; // here v may still not exist because of optimization because v still not necessary
   v.init(...); // here v exists
}
// here v does not exist
```

and the code generated by the compiler automatically calls the constructor and the destructor when needed.

Comment: It can be useful if you're doing something with an iterator of this vector that could be invalidated by an automatic reservation, therefore you need to know when this iterator would be invalidated. It's a pretty situational case but I think it could happen.

Comment: Of course. I mean, if you do not handle the case when your vector is doing a 'reserve' by itself, your eventual iterator would be invalidated. Hence, it can be useful in this particular case to reserve explicitly a new capacity.

Comment: @Doch88 I do not think the C++ norm speaks about that (may be I am wrong). For me to use the reverve can be an attempt to not increase the size in several times in case you know you will do a lot of `push_back` for instance, and at the end to only reserve the needed size when you stop to add element in it, that is all

Comment: @bruno From the 2012 standard, 23.3.6.8/5: "Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements
in the sequence. It is guaranteed that **no reallocation takes place** during insertions that happen after
a call to reserve() **until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than
the value of capacity()."** Keeping iterators valid through insertions is one of the two reasons for reserve() (the more obvious being better performance due to fewer re-allocations).